# Setting up Paypal account in Substruct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I am new to both paypal and substruct. I trying to integrate paypal with 'Substruct'. The problem I am facing is that the payment status codes are not being updated in the admin panel.
All of them are on Hold even when paypal sandbox successfully confirmed the orders. From the web somebody suggested that the 'notify_url' needs to be set in the confirm order form

Paypal documention says the same as well.

***https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables***

What value should I provide to the notify_url so that the webserver on my machine is notified. BTW my webserver is behind a LAN.

Answer (score 1):

check the substruct documentation @ http://code.google.com/p/substruct/wiki/PayPal